# Format time str with slicing

Tags: python, pandas

I have some time data that I need to convert to a proper datetime with

```
data['dep_time'] = pd.to_datetime(data['dep_time'], format='%H:%M').dt.time
```

The problem is in each cell I have an inconsistent number of digits

I might have '1714' or '714' or just '6'.

I want to use format to change each str to the format 00:00, but I have to start from the back of the str and assume that if I just have '6' it means '00:06'

```
        year  month  day  dep_time  dep_delay  arr_time  arr_delay  cancelled  \
103992  2014      5   11      1013         -2      1247        -13          0   
103993  2014      5   11      1929         -1      2215        -24          0   
103994  2014      5   11      1117          5      1355          9          0   
103995  2014      5   11       736        -10       924        -18          0   
103996  2014      5   11      1340          0      1647         10          0
```

Comment: What if the cell is `'111'`?

Comment: That would be 01:11

Comment: Then how is 11:01 formatted?

Comment: Just like that. My data says 1101 when it means that and I'm making some assumptions about the consistency of what I have

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using `str.pad`

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'time':['1', '12', '123', '1234']})
df.time.str.pad(4,side='left',fillchar='0')
Out[188]: 
0    0001
1    0012
2    0123
3    1234
Name: time, dtype: object
```

Or `rjust`

```
df.time.str.rjust(4,fillchar='0')
Out[190]: 
0    0001
1    0012
2    0123
3    1234
Name: time, dtype: object
```

Update

```
pd.to_datetime(df.time.str.pad(4,side='left',fillchar='0'),format='%H%M').dt.time
Out[199]: 
0    00:01:00
1    00:12:00
2    01:23:00
3    12:34:00
Name: time, dtype: object
```

Comment: Any idea why this data['dep_time'] = pd.to_datetime(data['dep_time'], format='%H:%M').dt.time isn't conveting it to datetime now?

Comment: Added data to question. Error I'm getting is 'ValueError: time data '24:00' does not match format '%H:%M' (match)'

Comment: Do I have to convert the column to a separate df for that to work? It doesn't seem to work on just the column because it's a Series object: 'Series' object has no attribute 'time' - so I'm doing data['dep_time'] = pd.to_datetime(data['dep_time'].time.str.pad(4,side='left',fillchar='0'),format='%H%M').dt.time

Comment: @Davtho1983 you are adding additional `time` here try `pd.to_datetime(data['dep_time'].str.pad(4,side='left',fillchar='0'),format='%H%M').dt.time `

Comment: That gives me ValueError: unconverted data remains: 0 - not sure what that means!

Comment: @Davtho1983 HHMM ... think about the hour , it should be 00 to 24 and mins should be 00 to 60 , you have some value exceed the range

Comment: @Davtho1983 adding `errors `, it will remain the error as NaT `pd.to_datetime(data['dep_time'].str.pad(4,side='left',fillchar='0'),format='%H%M',errors='coerce').dt.time`

Comment: Is there a way to find out which row is raising the error?

Answer (score 4):

In plain Python you can use [right justification](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.rjust):

```
for s in ('1', '12', '123', '1234'):
    print(s.rjust(4, '0'))
```

**output**

```
0001
0012
0123
1234
```

Comment: I'm trying not to execute a for loop for every cell in my data - is format faster?

Comment: @Davtho1983 with pandas you do `df[column].str.rjust(4, '0')`

Answer (score 2):

Not as elegant as some suggestions, but simple and may work for you?

```
dt = 'dep_time'.zfill(4)
dt = dt[:2] + ":" + dt[2:]
```

So for 1 you will get

```
00:01
```

and for 613:

```
 06:13
```

or more succinctly:

```
dt = '{0}:{1}'.format(date_time.zfill(4)[:2], date_time.zfill(4)[2:])
```

Answer (score 2):

Borrowing Wen's `df`

### `pandas.Series.str.zfill`

```
df.time.str.zfill(4)

0    0001
1    0012
2    0123
3    1234
Name: time, dtype: object
```

### Python 3.6 f-string

```
[f'{int(i):04d}' for i in df.time]

['0001', '0012', '0123', '1234']
```